# Does taking somebody's Commander phase that player out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

What does happen to the person if I take their Commander does the person phase out of the game for two turns? Because I thought I read it a couple months ago about that just not sure

Comment: As per my answer, this doesn't happen. If you could find the piece you read, we may be able to help you understand what it is trying to say.

Comment: Whilst the flavour of the Commander format is that the commander card "is" the player, and there are rules relating to the commander card, there's no requirement that the commander be on the battlefield or in the command zone for the player to play

Comment: related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41642/are-you-able-to-take-control-of-another-players-commander

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that by "person" you mean player, this cannot happen as a player cannot phase out; quoting [Rule 110.5](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020221118.pdf):

> 110.5 A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two
> possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out.
> Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.
>
> [...]
>
> 110.5d Only permanents have status.

More generally, there is absolutely nothing in the rules which means a similar effect to this (e.g. the commander itself phases out for one or more turns) happens; it being rather hard to prove a negative I can't give a rules citation here.

There could conceivably be an effect from specific cards which would make something like this happen, but I'm not aware of any; Scryfall returns nothing for ["phases out" and "two turns"](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&extras=true&lang=any&order=name&q=%28oracle%3A%22phases+out%22+oracle%3A%22two+turns%22%29&unique=cards).

Comment: If it was part of how Commander worked we ought to reference the commander website or comp rules rather than scryfall (which also don't mention phasing out for two turns).

Comment: @doppelgreener The point I was trying to make (apparently not very well) was that there could be a card which said something like "If you lose control of this permanent, you phase out for two turns" - so it's not Commander-specific.

Comment: Oh right, I misread that sentence and missed that detail somehow. Thanks.

Comment: More to the point, I don't think a player *can* phase out. Rule 110.5d is quite clear that only permanents can be phased in or out.

Comment: @Cadence I think that's an important part. The OP needs to understand that not only is there no such rule, but the very concept of "person phases out" doesn't make any sense to start with.

Comment: Edited to include!